# Is it significantly less challenging to build an ORC piston or turbine than the same for a water steam engine?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, turbines

An [organic rankine cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_Rankine_cycle) engine is a steam engine that uses, instead of water, a fluid with a higher vapor pressure. This allows a rankine cycle type process at lower temepratures, like the waste heat of a motor or geothermal energy.

I would expect the mechanical part of the ORC engine to be significantly easier to build, and thus cheaper, because the temperatures are lower and so thermal expansion is less of an issue. However, I don't know enough about constructing pistons or turbines to be sure. Can someone shed light on this?

Comment: the gases used most often for them are quite polluting or just generally dangerous when there is a leak

Comment: I'd have thought the differences were not vast unless your waterbased engine was very high performance. As an interested observer, but never having built one, in most cases the engines that I have seen amateurs build seem to be substantially over-engineered wrt crank shaft, bearings etc.  If you are building something with real world specific performance it may be different.